# How to calculate this equation?

Tags: hash

Can someone please explain to me what are the steps used to get this result (0.9154n+0.8876) from this equation
$$(2n+2){T}_{ecc}^{sm}+(2n){T}_{h}+(2n+2){T}_{ecc}^{pa}+(2n){T}_{ecc}^{sm-s} \approx 0.9154n + 0.8876?$$

where ${T}_{ecc}^{sm}$ =0.442,  ${T}_{h}$= 0.0001,  ${T}_{ecc}^{pa}$= 0.0018, and  ${T}_{ecc}^{sm-s}$= 0.0138

PS: These variables represent the Execution time of cryptographic operations in ms

Comment: this is off topic actually, it's just algebra and computation, but @kelalaka was helpful, as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sagemath with symbolic computations doesn't provide the same results. Contact the authors.

```
n = var('n');
a = 0.442
b = 0.0001
c = 0.0018
d = 0.0138
(2*n+2)*a + (2*n)*b + (2*n+2)*c + (2*n)*d
```

output

`0.915400000000000*n + 0.887600000000000`

---

$$(2*n+2)*a + (2*n)*b + (2*n+2)*c + (2*n)*d = $$

$$ 2n(a+b+c+d) + 2(a +c) $$

$$ 2n ( 0.442 + 0.0001 + 0.0018 + 0.0138) + 2 (0.442 + 0.0018)$$
$$ 2n ( 0.442 + 0.0019 + 0.0138) + 2 (0.4439)$$
$$ 2n ( 0.4439 + 0.0138) + 0.8878)$$
$$ 2n ( 0.4577 ) + 0.8878)$$
$$  0.9154n  + 0.8878)$$

Comment: Sorry, I've put the wrong result, I edited it now please have a look at it, Can you tell me the steps exactly that you used to get the result? I tried to count it but I didn't find the same result

Comment: Instead of calculating by hand, that is possible, I've used SageMath's [symbolic compuation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/calculus/calculus.html). `n = var('n');` declares a symbolic variable. The rest is renaming your variables and writing the equation.

Comment: It is the same result, now.

Comment: did you use SageMath in python to run it ?

Comment: you need sagemath for the symbolic computation

Comment: Thank you so much